# What is the legal principle for which a person is not guilty of another person's crimes

Tags: legal-terms, legal-concepts, jurisprudence

I'm asking a general question, not particular of the law of a specific country.

There is a named legal principle for which a person is not responsible for crimes, guilts or responsibilities of his ancestors, his city, nation, race, sex, or any group to which he belongs?

There are different legal principles for each of those categories? (example: family guilt vs nationality guilt)

There is a Latin phrase referring to that, or those principles?

Comment: I'm more familiar with terms for when a person *is* punished for the actions of others.  "Collective punishment" is one, "corruption of blood" is another special instance.

Comment: _Mens rea_ would be a sufficient principle, as your mind is not guilty for the action of others. This is of course a more fundamental and wide-reaching principle.

Comment: @NateEldredge You should write that up as an answer (you might add attainder, which is what leads to corruption of the blood.)

Comment: Corruption of blood is actually narrower than I had supposed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attainder#:~:text=Corruption%20of%20blood%20is%20one,their%20other%20relatives%20through%20him.

Comment: Also worth noting that it isn't universal. Many legal systems have held people responsible for the debts of their deceased ancestors and various kinds of collective punishment have been tolerated historically and even in the present day. For example, in Afghanistan it isn't uncommon to authorize the rape a woman as a traditional law punishment for an act committed by another member of her extended family.

Comment: Related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_libel

Comment: @ohwilleke it's also possible in western legal systems: directors can be criminally liable for the acts and omissions of their companies.